# I am getting error while passing parameters from service

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Here is the code and I am receiving an error while passing this parameter  from services.

```
export class CardsPage {
    currentItems: Item[];
    id: any;
    getData: Object;
    categories:any;
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public api:Api, navParams: 
   NavParams, items: Items, public http: HttpClient) {
         this.id = navParams.get('idName') ||'';
         console.log(this.id); 
 this.api.getCategoryPosts(this.id).subscribe(data=>{
   console.log(data)
    this.getData = data
 },err=>{
 console.log(err)
 })
 }
  openItem(item){
     this.navCtrl.push('ItemDetailPage', {
     itemName: item
  });
  }
 }
```

Here is my Ts file:

```
getCategoryPosts(category: any) {
   return this.http.get(`${this.api_url}/posts? 
   categories=${category.id}`);
  }
```

The error that i am receiving is Reference error: category is not defined Reference error. Category is not defined at new CardsPage

Comment: Why are you using OR operation ? this.id = navParams.get('idName') ||'';

Comment: no I havent used it

Answer (score 0):

Hello just use **ionViewWillEnter** to get your parameter and no need to use OR operation while getting parameter so here is the solution.

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
   this.id = navParams.get('idName')
}
```

then use ionViewDidEnter to fetch data through service.

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
       this.api.getCategoryPosts(this.id).subscribe(data=>{
           console.log(data)
           this.getData = data
       },err=>{
           console.log(err)
       })
}
```